# How do I actually import external fonts to my website (CSS)

Tags: html, css, import, font-family

I searched the web and look for ways to add an external fonts to the web or CSS. I know we should use #font-face to do that. But, my website doesn't load the font when I reload. Can someone see the problems for me?
This is my codes:

````
    <style> 
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'vcr_osd_monoregular';
    src: url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('vcr_osd_mono-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
    h1 {
       font-size: 90px;
       font-family: "vcr_osd_monoregular", sans-serif;
       color: yellow;
}
</style>```
Instead of printing out vcr_osd_monoregular font, it prints out sans-serif. Please help.
````

Comment: just pointing a few things out : you have an extra ``` there and also the text is inside the code fences

Comment: Where are the font files in your project? And where is this CSS file?

Comment: Can you follow that url back to your font file in the browser? If not then that path is wrong. Make sure the font weight is correct, you have to call the right weight for the font type, 400 regular, 800 bold, etc. And check the font file format it looks like ttf not woff2: https://www.dafont.com/vcr-osd-mono.font but you can convert that on fontsquirrel.com